# Rust: impl From<_> for usize, u64, u32, etc

Tags: rust, type-conversion

Let S be a struct. I want to implement From for all uint types. Is there a terse way to do this?

E.g., I want to write this code

```
impl From<S> for usize {
    fn from(s: S) -> usize {
        s.field_a + s.field_b    
    }
}

impl From<S> for u64 {
    fn from(s: S) -> u64 {
        s.field_a + s.field_b    
    }
}

impl From<S> for u32 {
    fn from(s: S) -> u32 {
        s.field_a + s.field_b    
    }
}

...
```

as

```
impl From<S> for uint {
    fn from(s: S) -> uint {
        s.field_a + s.field_b    
    }
}
```

My first thought was to use traits to group all the uints a la [how we pass traits as parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html). Here's my attempt:

```
use std::ops::Add;

impl From<S> for impl From + Add {
    fn from<T: From + Add>(s: S) -> T {
        T::from(s.field_a) + T::from(s.field_b)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work and feels janky (uints aren't just things that impl From and Add).

Don't know where to go from here! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A macro could work. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab5726fe3b738f728ccbdcdd0093cf61)

```
struct S {
    field_a: u8,
    field_b: u8,
}

macro_rules! impl_from_s {
    ($($uint_type: ty),*) => {
        $(
            impl From<S> for $uint_type {
                fn from(s: S) -> $uint_type {
                    <$uint_type>::from(s.field_a) + <$uint_type>::from(s.field_b)
                }
            }
        )*
    }
}

impl_from_s!(u8, u16, u32, u64, u128);
```

Comment: This looks like it works, but I'm a bit disappointed there's not a simpler way. I will accept this answer in a few days if no one comes up with something easier.

Comment: Just want to come back and say thank you! I use this answer all the time!

Comment: did you find a nicer solution?